# Exception in thread-1 is throwing an UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, multithreading

In my script when I run it I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "D:\DPS\polling_DO_EEM_RPP01_v3_test.py", line 721, in cloneInit
    processRawOnly(dupName, dupDict, raw, last, stop, rawName, rawDict, x, y)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'processRawOnly' referenced before assignment
```

The local variable mentioned here though is not a variable but a function. I have checked to see if I accidentally declared a variable with the same name and I have not.

The function that creates the thread is below:

```
def startCloneThread():
    threads = []

    try:
        if any('ems' in file for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            print('Clone EMS')
            tEMS=threading.Thread(target = cloneInit, args = (suffixesEMS, suffixes2EMS, suffixes3EMS, initListEMS, initCSVEMS, ctfEMS, gccEMS, rawEMS, csvEMS, lastEMS, stopEMS, runDictEMS, csvDictEMS, rawDictEMS, dupDictEMS, runNameEMS, csvNameEMS, rawNameEMS, dupNameEMS))
            threads.append(tEMS)
        if any('study1' in file for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            print('Clone STUDY1')
            tSTDY1=threading.Thread(target = cloneInit, args = (suffixesStdy1, suffixes2Stdy1, suffixes3Stdy1, initListStdy1, initCSVStdy1, ctfStdy1, gccStdy1, rawStdy1, csvStdy1, lastStdy1, stopStdy1, runDictStdy1, csvDictStdy1, rawDictStdy1, dupDictStdy1, runNameStdy1, csvNameStdy1, rawNameStdy1, dupNameStdy1))
            threads.append(tSTDY1)
        if any('study2' in file for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            print('Clone STUDY2')
            tSTDY2=threading.Thread(target = cloneInit, args = (suffixesStdy2, suffixes2Stdy2, suffixes3Stdy2, initListStdy2, initCSVStdy2, ctfStdy2, gccStdy2, rawStdy2, csvStdy2, lastStdy2, stopStdy2, runDictStdy2, csvDictStdy2, rawDictStdy2, dupDictStdy2, runNameStdy2, csvNameStdy2, rawNameStdy2, dupNameStdy2))
            threads.append(tSTDY2)
        if any('study3' in file for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            print('Clone STUDY3')
            tSTDY3=threading.Thread(target = cloneInit, args = (suffixesStdy3, suffixes2Stdy3, suffixes3Stdy3, initListStdy3, initCSVStdy3, ctfStdy3, gccStdy3, rawStdy3, csvStdy3, lastStdy3, stopStdy3, runDictStdy3, csvDictStdy3, rawDictStdy3, dupDictStdy3, runNameStdy3, csvNameStdy3, rawNameStdy3, dupNameStdy3))
            threads.append(tSTDY3)
        if any('study4' in file for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            print('Clone STUDY4')
            tSTDY4=threading.Thread(target = cloneInit, args = (suffixesStdy4, suffixes2Stdy4, suffixes3Stdy4, initListStdy4, initCSVStdy4, ctfStdy4, gccStdy4, rawStdy4, csvStdy4, lastStdy4, stopStdy4, runDictStdy4, csvDictStdy4, rawDictStdy4, dupDictStdy4, runNameStdy4, csvNameStdy4, rawNameStdy4, dupNameStdy4))
            threads.append(tSTDY4)
        
        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
    except:
        ScriptRunTime = runTime(ScriptStartTime)
        RunTimeMessage = traceback.print_exc()
        logging.warning(RunTimeMessage)
```

The error gets thrown whenever `processRawOnly()` gets called, it works fine when
`lookForProcessingFiles()` gets called. I tried switching the order of when both functions gets called but it made no difference.
Both functions are defined above both `cloneInit()` and `startCloneThread()`.
Anyone have any idea of why the `processRawOnly()` is causing the unboundLocalError?
The function where the error occurs is below:

```
def cloneInit(suffixes, suffixes2, suffixes3, initList, initCSV, ctf, gcc, raw, csv, last, stop, runDict, csvDict, rawDict, dupDict, runName, csvName, rawName, dupName):
    if any((file.endswith(suffixes2) or file.endswith(raw))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)): 
        time.sleep(5)
        ScriptRunTime = runTime(ScriptStartTime)
        RunTimeMessage = 'I am cloneInit()  - Run Time: ' + str(ScriptRunTime)
        logging.warning(RunTimeMessage)

        if any((file.endswith(suffixes2))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data):
                if file.endswith(gcc) or file.endswith(ctf):
                    initList.append(file)
                    print(initList)

            if len(initList) >= 2: #if items exist in list
                for x,y in itertools.combinations(initList,2):
                    if (x[:48]) == (y[:48]) and x.endswith(ctf) and y.endswith(gcc):
                        if not any((file.endswith(csv))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
                            moveInitFilesRaw(dupName, dupDict, rawName, rawDict, x, y)
                            processRawOnly(dupName, dupDict, raw, last, stop, rawName, rawDict, x, y)
                        else:
                            moveInitFilesRun(dupName, dupDict, runName, runDict, x, y)
                            lookForProcessingFiles(dupName, dupDict, raw, csv, last, stop, runName, runDict, x, y)      
                del initList[:]

            elif len(initList) <= 1 :
                for file in initList:
                    if file.endswith(ctf):
                        if any(f.endswith(csv) for f in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
                            moveInitFilesRun(dupName, dupDict, runName, runDict, file)
                            lookForProcessingFiles(dupName, dupDict, raw, csv, last, stop, runName, runDict, file)
                        else:
                            moveInitFilesRaw(dupName, dupDict, rawName, rawDict, file)
                            processRawOnly(dupName, dupDict, raw, last, stop, rawName, rawDict, file)
                    elif file.endswith(gcc):
                        if any((file.endswith(csv))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
                            moveInitFilesRun(dupName, dupDict, runName, runDict, file)
                            lookForProcessingFiles(dupName, dupDict, raw, csv, last, stop, runName, runDict, file)
                        else:
                            moveInitFilesRaw(dupName, dupDict, rawName, rawDict, file)
                            processRawOnly(dupName, dupDict, raw, last, stop, rawName, rawDict, file)
                del initList[:]

        elif not any((file.endswith(suffixes))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data):
                if file.endswith(raw) and (len(runDict) == 0) and (len(csvDict) == 0):
                    if (len(file) == 84):
                        rawFile = file[:32] + file[64:-4] + '_chkRaw1'
                    else:
                        rawFile = file[:32] + file[62:-4] + '_chkRaw1'
                
                    if rawFile not in rawDict:
                        rawDict[rawFile] = ''
                        dictSave(rawName, rawDict)
                    processRawOnly = (dupName, dupDict, raw, last, stop, rawName, rawDict, rawFile )

        elif not any((file.endswith(suffixes2))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data):
                if file.endswith(raw) or file.endswith(csv) and (len(runDict) == 0):
                    if (len(runDict) == 0):
                        initCSV.append(file)

            if initCSV and (len(runDict) == 0 and len(rawDict) == 0): #if items exist in list
                for a,b in itertools.combinations(initCSV,2):
                    if (a[:32]) == (b[:32]) and (a[64:-4] == b[64:-22] or a[62:-4] == b[62:-22]) and a.endswith(raw) and b.endswith(csv):
                        if (len(a) == 84):
                            rawBase = a[:32] + a[64:-4] + '_chkRaw1'
                        else:
                            rawBase = a[:32] + a[62:-4] + '_chkRaw1'
                        
                        if (len(b) == 102):
                            csvBase = b[:32] + b[64:-22] + '_chkCSV1'
                        else:
                            csvBase = b[:32] + b[62:-22] + '_chkCSV1'
                    
                        if rawBase not in csvDict:
                            csvDict[rawBase] = ''
                            dictSave(csvName, csvDict)
                        
                        if csvBase not in csvDict:
                            csvDict[csvBase] = ''
                            dictSave(csvName, csvDict)
                        lookForProcessingFiles(dupName, dupDict, raw, csv, last, stop, csvName, csvDict,rawBase,csvBase)
                del initCSV[:]

    else:
        if any((file.endswith(stop))for file in os.listdir(Incoming_Data)):
            for f in os.listdir(Incoming_Data):
                    if f.startswith(stop):
                        shutil.move(Incoming_Data + f, DPT_INPUT_ST + f)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but is `processRawOnly = (dupName, dupDict, raw, . . .` supposed to be `processRawOnly(dupName, dupDict, raw, . . .`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate two days and I kept missing that, thanks that was the cause of my woes!!

Comment: Oh, good. Glad that helped.